# Response-lag in new laptop on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: performance

I recently purchased a new laptop (CPU: Ryzen 9 5800HX, GPU: NVIDIA GTX 3050, 16 GB RAM).

On *Ubuntu 20.04*, I am experiencing response lag from time to time in almost all everyday uses.

For example, if I minimize a tab, I might see it happen a second later (though most of the time there is no lag).

I am also experiencing cursor-movement lag in text editing quite frequently (eg. using vim). Also seeing occasional video stuttering while playing video either using SM Player (or any other player) or on YouTube.

However, I was able to play Crysis 3 on *Windows 10* without any glitches and also other games, and also did not experience any other issues, apart from the issues inherent in Windows.

Can someone see what could be the problem in Ubunutu and how could this be fixed?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the response on running `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 25a2 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10ec
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1638 (rev c4)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10ec
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @Pilot6 Currently I am indeed using the driver recommended by NVIDIA.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited the quesiton.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have re-edited with th eresponse typed out.

Comment: It looks OK. The driver is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the `Software & Updates`, press on `Settings`, open `Additional Drivers` tab. Try to choose and install `proprietary` driver, preferably `tested`. I chose first from the top.

Comment: Giving it a shot. Thanks.